# Problem with Dependency Injection and Get It in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I have been learning about Dependency Injection and now I have implemented an example in dart. But I'm facing an issue with get_it package. Here's the code:

'MessageService.dart'

```
abstract class MessageService {
  void sendMessage(String msg, String rec);
}

class EmailServiceImpl implements MessageService {
  @override
  void sendMessage(String message, String receiver) {
    //logic to send email
    print("Email sent to $receiver with message $message.");
  }
}

class SMSServiceImpl implements MessageService {
  @override
  void sendMessage(String message, String receiver) {
    //logic to send SMS
    print("SMS sent to $receiver with message $message.");
  }
}
```

'injection_container.dart'

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

import 'MessageService.dart';
import 'main.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;

void init() async {
  getIt.registerFactory<Client>(() => Client());
  getIt.registerFactory<MyApplication>(() => MyApplication(EmailServiceImpl()));
  getIt.registerFactory<MessageService>(() => EmailServiceImpl());
  getIt.registerFactory<MessageService>(() => SMSServiceImpl());
}
```

'main.dart'

```
import 'MessageService.dart';
import 'injection_container.dart' as di;

void main() {
  di.init();
  di.getIt<Client>().send();
}

class MyApplication {
  MessageService _service;

  MyApplication(this._service);

  void processMessages(String msg, String rec) {
    //do some msg validation, manipulation logic etc
    this._service.sendMessage(msg, rec);
  }
}

class Client {
  void send() {
    MyApplication app = di.getIt<MyApplication>();
    app.processMessages("Hi Bill", "bill@abc.com");
  }
}
```

But when registering both EmailServiceImpl and SMSServiceImpl in injection_container.dart it gives me in error as : Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Object/factory with  type MessageService is already registered inside GetIt.

If I comment out SMSServiceImpl registration it works fine. Can someone tell what's the problem?
And it would be helpful if someone can review my Dependency Injection example. Is it the right way to present Dependency Injection?

Comment: Why do you want to define both these services as MessageService in getit. How are you want to get one versus the other?

Comment: I thought if we want to extend our application to provide/replace an additional messaging feature, such as SMS then we would just change it in the injector file. And getting dependency by above method is the only way i know. I don't know if it's the correct one. Please tell the correct one if it's not.

Comment: The both services are defined as MessageService because MyApplication has a dependency of type MessageService. So you have to mention the type of those services. Hence MessageService is provided in get_it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
getIt.registerFactory<MessageService>(() => EmailServiceImpl());
getIt.registerFactory<MessageService>(() => SMSServiceImpl());
```

GetIt only allows (by default) one instance of a type.

So your code is trying to register two instances of a same type (MessageService).
From GetIt doc

> You have to pass a factory function func that returns an NEW instance of an implementation of T. Each time you call get() you will get a new instance returned.

So when you call GetIt.I.get() it wont know if it's a EmailServiceImpl or a SMSServiceImpl

**Try this**

```
getIt.registerFactory<EmailServiceImpl>(() => EmailServiceImpl());
getIt.registerFactory<SMSServiceImpl>(() => SMSServiceImpl());
```

You can also allow reassingments so your code will work the way it is.

`GetIt.I.allowReassignment = true`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out, that the accepted answer is no longer valid. `get_it` does allow the registration of multiple instances of a type using "named registration" with the argument `instanceName`. To quote from the [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#named-registration):

> All registration functions have an optional named parameter instanceName. Providing a name with factory/singleton here registers that instance with that name and a type.